# How to suppress warnings in maven output when using maven-checkstyle-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

My build fails on checkstyle errors (not warnings). As long as there are any checkstyle errors i want the warnings are not shown in the (maven produced) output. How to achieve this?

```
# First is error, should be reported, second is a warning, should not be reported in the maven output. 
...data/Decimal.java:286:31: '7L' is a magic number.
.../data/Decimal.java:296:5: warning: Missing a Javadoc comment.
```

UPDATE: See my comment. This question is NOT about suppressing specific warnings! It is only about not displaying all warnings in the maven output!

Comment: Do your want to ignore these warnings or fix these warnings?

Comment: Ehm, type `maven checkstyle plugin suppress warning` into Google and read first few results (i.e. Checkstyle plugin documentation)?

Comment: Maybe i am not clear enough: i do not want to suppress specific warnings. I just (and only) want them not to show up in the output. See my updated question

Comment: You can try to configure `logViolationsToConsole` in your pom or use the property `-Dcheckstyle.console=false` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise tried that. It is all-or-nothing (so warnings *and* errors or no output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such option in checkstyle.

You can use filters to show you only errors, but there is no option to hide events by level if higher level exists. You can write such filter http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingfilters.html#Writing_Filters

Comment: I already came to this conclusion myself. Good to have this confirmed! Tried `SeverityMatchFilter` and it comes close, but is not exactly where i am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with lots of warnings. As a quick hack it is possible to just filter out "warning" lines with inverted grep match:

```
mvn clean install | grep -v warning
```

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this, since it is a valid work around and the accepted answer says it can't be done unless you write it yourself.

Comment: It's downvoted since OP wanted to suppress checkstyle warnings, not any maven warning. Although a grep approach could work with some more complicated regex.

Comment: It is indeed very helpful even though it may not have directly answer the question. Thanks @Anton